# Do I need to use SES with Elastic Beanstalk to send mail for a contact form?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just want to create a simple "contact us" form on a Rails Elastic Beanstalk instance. So at this time I will only be sending to one e-mail (one that control). Is there a better way then setting up a production email service? At least to me, it seems like SES is overkill?

(I don't need help on creating the contact form, just the hosting setup as it pertains to AWS and EB.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Production SES is definitely an overkill for your case (assuming there will be less than 200 contacts per day), but sandbox environment is just right. All you need to do is to verify your email - [Verifying Email Addresses in Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html). It is really easy to integrate with and the next time you will need email on production level, you will be already familiar with SES.

Comment: Do I just use sendmail in my instance to send then? Or are there unique details for the configuration that I'd use with the Rails mailer? Am I still limited to 200 emails a day?